# How to join multiple machins connected via enthernet cabels (in one NAT) into one counting resource using new .net 4 Parallel Programming APIs?

Tags: api, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, nat

How to join multiple machins connected via enthernet cabels (in one NAT) into one counting resource using new .net 4 Parallel Programming APIs? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The .NET 4 Task Parallel Library is designed for writing parallel applications on a single multicore machine with shared memory, not a distributed cluster of machines. If you want to do this then you should look at [MPI.NET](http://osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/). MPI is a message passing implementation designed to allow you to write distributed applications on a cluster.